# How to implement favorite tweet function on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, slrequest, acaccount

I'm making a Twitter application on iOS 7 using [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) .

I want to add function of favorite in my application.
To getting user stream I used STTwitter, then I want to favorite tweet.
But STTwitter doesn't have such function, so I decided to use `ACAccount` and `SLRequest` .

I coded as shown below, referencing [here](http://www.slideshare.net/satoshinakagawa543/twitter-client-seminar) (on slide 88 and 89), but status code 400 was returned.
How can I fix it? Any helps would greatly help.

```
- (IBAction)favButtonTouchDown:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"Now trying to favorite tweet id: %@", _tweetID);

ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
_account = [accountStore accountWithIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType: accountType
                                      options: nil
                                   completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                       if (granted)
                                       {
                                           NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType: accountType];
                                           if ([accounts count] > 0)
                                           {
                                               _account = accounts[0];
                                               _accountID = _account.identifier;
                                               NSLog(@"Getting account is OK. Account ID is: %@", _accountID);
                                           }
                                       } else {
                                           NSLog(@"Error while getting account.");
                                       }
                                   }];

NSString *urlString =
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/create.json?id=%@", _tweetID];
NSLog(@"URL will be: %@", urlString);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

// NSDictionary *params = @{@"trim_user" : @"1"};

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                  URL:url
                                           parameters:nil];

[request setAccount: _account];

UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
application.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                     NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse,
                                     NSError *error) {
    if (responseData) {

        NSString *httpErrorMessage = nil;

        if (urlResponse.statusCode >= 200 && urlResponse.statusCode < 300) {

            NSDictionary *postResponseData =
            [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData
                                            options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                              error: NULL];
            NSLog(@"SUCCESS! Added Favorite Tweet with ID: %@", postResponseData[@"id_str"]);

        } else {

            httpErrorMessage =
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The response status code is %ld",
             (long)urlResponse.statusCode];
            NSLog(@"HTTP Error: %@", httpErrorMessage);

        }

    } else {

        NSLog(@"ERROR: An error occured while posting %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        application.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    });

}];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: STTwitter had methods for most if not all Twitter API endpoints. Use this one https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/STTwitter/STTwitterAPI.h#L1263-L1274 for the favorites/create endpoint.

Comment: Oh, it was my fault... thank you notifying me. I'll check it and rewrite the code :) !